# Proof relating to strictly diagonal dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I came across a question relating to strictly diagonal dominant matrix, the question is as follows:

> Let $M$ be a $n \times n$ strictly diagonally dominant matrix.
>
> Define $K_j = B (\mathbf L + \mathbf U)$, where $B$ is the inverse of $A$, and $A$ is a diagonal matrix whose entries are the diagonal entries of $M$. $−$ is the strictly lower-triangular matrix of $M$, $–$ is the strictly upper-triangular matrix of $M$, $i$ and $j$ are the row and column of the matrices respectively.
>
> Show that $\|K_j\|_∞ ≜ \max_{1≤i≤n} |K_i|$ (i.e. the maximum sum of all elements in the same row) is strictly less than $1$.

My attempt:

I tried to construct arbitrary n x n matrices M, -L and -U, and try to compare the entries of M and entries of LU.

But I failed to observe any particular pattern, and have no idea how to go on.

Could anyone please give me some hints to go on the proof?

Thank you!